# DeltaImport for FileSystem Datasource in Solr

Tags: jdbc, solr, filesystems, data-import

is it possible to run deltaImport for Filesystem Solr DataSource to be done by curl (crontab).
for JDBC we can run delta import in crontab in something like this

```
4-59/4 * * * * curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/solr/MyCore/dataimport_30?command=delta-import
```

Now I have another datasource built on file system, but i am not seeing any **dataimport properties** file in the conf directory of my core.

***The Question:* How can i run delta import OR full-import for a filesystem datasource in solr?**

Comment: Can you trigger the delta import from the Admin UI? If yes, then maybe the problem is with cron. If no, then it is your Solr configuration that might be incorrect. You need to divide the problem a couple more times to see where exactly the issue is.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch, based on [Solr Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) , **The only EntityProcessor which supports delta is SqlEntityProcessor!** , so is there any way to do full import instead using command line

Comment: The solution process is still the same. Can you trigger it from UI? Behind the scenes it is still just the URL call. Figure that part out before worrying about cron.

Comment: it can be done by Lucidworks, but it needs login to do so